# Automatically Import Excel Data to SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, excel, access

This question has been asked before but I haven't found an answer that works for me and my limitations.

I have an excel spreadsheet that is currently being used to input data with 20+ records each time. I want to be able to import this data into an existing sharepoint list. I'm using office 2010 and SP 2013. I don't have Visual Studio so I'm looking to do this with VBA or out of the box.

So my idea right now is to create a new worksheet in the workbook with the formatted data, then upload the workbook to a document library in sharepoint and run a workflow that would then take the (hidden) worksheet with the formatted data and update an existing sharepoint list. Is this possible without visual studio?

Alternatively I could import the data to access and then link my access DB to a sharepoint list?

I haven't really gotten too far in my research on any of these scenarios yet so I was hoping I could get some insight before wasting a week finding out what I can't actually do.

Comment: I can't think of any non-coding solution, you will need Visual Studio.. But I would love to be corrected :)

Comment: Do you want to create new items or update existing list items?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do both eventually but right now just add to existing list

Comment: Hi @John I have a very thorough and tested solution on a related question that I believe will help. It covers all Column Types and works mostly out of the box, with the exception of some PowerShell if your import includes User field types.
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 3):

My solution was this:
http://rstagg.com/2010/04/13/how-to-bulk-upload-and-synchronize-data-into-sharepoint-using-the-excel-add-in-and-sharepoint-designer-workflows/

I installed an add-in for excel that let's me sync a data sheet to a list in sharepoint. So I update that data sheet, and then sync the data with it. So far it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the interesting solution! it would be better to not only link the blog post, but also describe the approach you took (you can also quote the original source), such that in case the linked page should not be available any more, the answer here remains useful.

Comment: as @MostlyHarmless said, the link is now invalid. the approach/add-in should have been mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to identify the new data in the excel document then you can copy that data and paste your excel data directly into the existing sharepoint list in Internet Explorer while in edit mode.

The data you are pasting has to match up with the restrictions of the place you are pasting it. So if column one is a single line text field with a 20 character limit then you can’t paste a row of data whose column one as 45 characters.

I had no problem pasting my excel data into sharepoint about 50+ rows at a time.